# Java finding duplicate stings in array and adding corresponding int values

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, treemap

I am somewhat new to programming and struggle with this task. I have a table with names (strings) and corresponding values (int). Now I'm looking for duplicates in the names and add up the int values if the name already exists in the table.

I have a vague idea of how I could do this but I'm also pretty sure this is not the ideal solution to the problem. I'm trying to optimize the results that I am getting. My idea is using 2 Arrays, one for the names and one for the numbers, if there is a duplicate name in the Array, I'll go to the same position in the numbers Array and add the corresponding numbers.
My initial idea looks like this:

```
String[] names = {a,b,a,a,c,b};
Integer[] numbers = {5,2,3,1,2,1};

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
        if (names[i].equals(names[j]) ) {
           numbers[i] += numbers[j]
        } System.out.println("Name: " + names[i] + " Amount: " + numbers[i])
    }
}
```

The intended output should be along the lines of this:
`a = 10
b = 3
c = 1`

I know this is a brute force method but I need to know the positions in the Array for this to work. I have no experience with treemaps but that might be an easier solution to the problem at hand. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code will not even compile.

Comment: A little hint to ease your pain: [You could use a map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm)

Comment: How is the result `a=10` and `c=1` ? Shouldn't it be `a=5+3+1=9` and `c=2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already suggested it in the comments: You can use a map to count all the values.
Here is an **intentionally verbose** example (to make clear what happens):

```
    String[] names = {"a","b","a","a","c","b"};
    Integer[] numbers = {5,2,3,1,2,1};

    Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (totals.containsKey(names[i])) {
            totals.put(names[i], totals.get(names[i]) + numbers[i]);
        } else {
            totals.put(names[i], numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(totals);
```

So if the name is already in the map, just increase the count by the new number. If it's not, add a new map entry with the number.
Beware that for this to work, your two arrays must be of equal length!

This will print:

```
{a=9, b=3, c=2}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. By the way, you can easily access the values in the map the same way it is done in the code above: `totals.get("something")` ... or iterate over the map: `for (String name : totals.keySet()){ //call totals(name) here }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Treemap to contain the duplicity and total sum corresponding to your input String. Also using treemap, your output will be in sorted format if that you require.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String[] names = {"a","b","a","a","c","b"};
  Integer[] numbers = {5,2,3,1,2,1};
  Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (!map.containsKey(names[i])) {
      map.put(names[i], 0);
    }
    map.put(names[i], map.get(names[i]) + numbers[i]);
  }

  for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println( key +" = " + map.get(key));
  }
}
```

The output for above code will be (as pointed by @vincrichaud):

```
a = 9
b = 3
c = 2
```

Comment: why `TreeMap`? why not plain `HashMap`?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Actually the reason is in the answer: *"output will be in sorted format"*. It's not a bad idea.

Comment: Tree Map will provided the output in sorted form while hashmap will provide entries in random order. By looking at the output, I will go with treeMap here. Also mentioned the same in my answer.

Comment: it is not required in question. why invent requirements ?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, It's just I inferred from the output of the above program that if I used hashMap the output would have been random, so I went with Treemap. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"a","b","a","a","c","b"};
        Integer[] numbers = {5,2,3,1,2,1};

        Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
            String key = names[i];
            Integer previousNumber = occurrences.getOrDefault(key, 0);  //Previously stored number
            Integer correspondingNumber = numbers[i];   //Delta for specified name
            occurrences.put(key, previousNumber + correspondingNumber); //Storing new value
        }

        //Print result
        occurrences.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Name: " + key + " Amount: " + value));
    }
}
```

Maps allows you to asign some kind of value to some unique key.
Generally put/retrieval operations of Maps are said to be of O(1) time complexity, which makes them a perfect solution to your problem.
The most basic implementation is HashMap, but if you want to keep the order of names when iterating, just use the LinkedHashMap.
On the other hand, if you want your data to be sorted in some manner, then you are likely to use TreeMap.

EDIT:
Like Sharon Ben Asher mentioned in comments section below, you can use merge() method to shorten the code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"a","b","a","a","c","b"};
        Integer[] numbers = {5,2,3,1,2,1};

        Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
            occurrences.merge(names[i], numbers[i], Integer::sum);

        //Print result
        occurrences.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Name: " + key + " Amount: " + value));
    }
}
```

But I broke it down a little in the first answer just to give you a better explanation of how do the maps work. Basically you use methods like get() (getOrDefault() is a variant of it, which returns value even if no mapping was found for given key) and put() allow you to commit new mapping/override existing for a given key.

Comment: if you are already using Map new methods, why not not use [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I modified my answer, thank you for a remark.

Answer (score -2):

Using Map will suffice your requirement. It could be done as below

String[] names = {"a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "b"};

Integer[] numbers = {5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1};

Map expectedOut = new HashMap();

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  if (expectedOut.containsKey(names[i]))
    expectedOut.put(names[i], expectedOut.get(names[i]) + numbers[i]);
  else
    expectedOut.put(names[i], numbers[i]);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> out : expectedOut.entrySet())
  System.out.println(out.getKey() + " = " + out.getValue());
```

}

Answer (score -3):

You can use Map interface. 
Use your String array "names" as keys. Write a for loop for it and inside: 
If your map contains the key, get the value and sum with the new value.

PS: Couldn't write code right now, I can update it later.